Impedance matching T/R switch
I do drive a piezo as transceiver. My transmitter provides square burst around 10Vpp which is too big for simply switching through a diode by dc biasing. I found out that bridge rectifier structure can be used for this task. I modified my design and designed this circuit. Impedance matching part might be not well built. I set values by approaching , making assumptions and the way of trial and error in the Lt-Spice.
After the burst , TXENABLE goes down and any echo signal must pass. I put pictures below. I want your comment and suggestions for my design phase becasue I almost did no calculations.


